# Cannot collapse a revision preview while a rate limit message is visible

Tags: bug, rate-limiting, error-message, activity

In the profile activity page, I opened a revision preview from a list of my own revisions by clicking on the edit summary, as that allows you to drop open the revision itself in its inline view.

I then tried to open another revision preview, and was stopped from loading it because you cannot load more than one revision per second (which is by design and functions properly.)

With this message still visible, I opened the revision preview (after waiting the designated amount of time,) then went to close it not long afterwords. The preview arrow that indicates whether a revision is shown or collapsed indicated that it was collapsed, but the revision itself does not collapse. The error message is closed, but the revision doesn't hide until I click to reopen it, and then close it again.

My explanation is pretty wordy, so here's a .gif demonstrating this.

[image: Demonstration of revision collapse failure]

Things get a bit weirder when you attempt to open and close this preview multiple times in a row, presumably because the error message does not have enough time to close (though that part's just my suspicion.) Here's a .gif demonstrating that behavior:

[image: Demonstrating trying to open and close the revision preview a lot of times in a row]

This latter issue doesn't seem to be something a user would normally do, but it would probably be fixed as a result of the former issue being addressed.

Could this problem be looked into?